# How can I access the AspNetUsers table's columns?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

So, I have this custom user that has properties `FullName` and `ProfileImage`.
I have made everything properly and in the `dbo.AspNetUsers` table in the database I see that the two columns are there and are populated.

However, when I try to access those columns in the database there is nothing suggested via IntelliSense and I can't access them for the life of me.

Been reading around about it, however I could not figure out why I can't access it.

Pseudocode example

```
private readonly OnlineCardShopDbContext data;

...

public SomeConstructor(OnlineCardShopDbContext data){
   this.data = data;
}

...

var dbUsers = this.data.Users.{none of the two columns' names here}
```

Comment: `this.data.Users` is (presumably) a DbSet which won't contain any references to the "columns" as you put it. Rather it gives you access to IQueryables from which you can build LINQ queries to, which is probably what you're after. What are you trying to do, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You can't access the columns with this query.

You should use `LINQ` methods like `Where` or `Select` ie with this query you can select only `FullName`:

```
var dbUsers = this.data.Users.Select(user=>new { user.FullName }).ToList();
```

Read more in [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/)

Comment: Thank you very much. Been struggling for a while with it. You are the man!